# How to redirect 502 bad gateway in php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to redirect 502 bad gateway in php?. I have tried to set 502 bad gateway in header redirect location.

header('502.html');

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Would you like to show a 502 bad gateway error or do you want to show a custom HTML page? By the way: a 502 means PHP has encountered a huge error which it can't recover from so PHP can't handle it because the process has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Location` to the beginning, like so:

```
header('Location: 502.html');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php